# Do i Need to Add android.permission.INTERNET for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-performance

Do i need to add android.permission.INTERNET for Firebase Analytics?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you should add internet permission to communicate through to internet, which Firebase crashlytics do that